# UWP CommandBar overlapping

Tags: xaml, uwp, overlapping, commandbar

I have an issue with CommandBar in UWP Apps (see pictures below)

[image]
here you can see the *CommandBar* in CompactMode and a *TextBlock* with Text "Title". When I now expand (click on the three dots) the *CommandBar*, the TextBlock disappears, like shown here:

[image]
How can I prevent the *TextBlock* from disappearing?

When I close the expanded *CommandBar*, it goes back to the state, from picture 1, showing the *TextBlock*.

The Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="cmdBarDesktop" Grid.Row="0">
  <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact" IsOpen="True" IsSticky="True">
    <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="AppBarListDesktop" Icon="List" Label="Listenform" Grid.Column="1" Click="AppBarList_Click" />
        <AppBarButton x:Uid="AppBarAdd" Icon="Add" Label="Hinzufügen" Grid.Column="3" Click="AppBarAdd_Click" />
    </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
  </CommandBar>
</Grid>

<Grid x:Name="titleGrid" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Text="Hausaufgaben" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside **Content** of the CommandBar control you can add a TextBlock.

```
 <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact">
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Title" />
            </CommandBar.Content>

            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Icon="List"
                              Label="Listenform" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="Add"
                              Label="Hinzufügen" />
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
 </CommandBar>
```

It will solve your problem in both scenarios.